# Run add_action( 'save_post' 'my_function') in Scheduling posts

Tags: wordpress, function, post, save, action

this is my function and this is work good when i publish or update posts. but i want this action working on scheduling posts :

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_custum' );

 function my_custum( $post_id ) {

   $var = 'Hello';

   update_post_meta($post_id, "talk", $var);

   return $post;
 }
```

how can run this action on Scheduling posts ?

Comment: any idea ?    How Can Run save_post on Scheduling post ?

Comment: Is not there a man in the world to give me the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'future_post', 'my_custum' );
```

Comment: YES WORK! you are the best. Thanks